# Chart component for Monotouch?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, charts

For my client I have to develop a dashboard for the iPad (in Monotouch), showing several charts. Is there a chart component available for MonoTouch? Or does anybody have an idea to generate charts for the iPad?

Thanks, 
Danny

Comment: Are you able to import libraries from .Net component vendors like Telerik or DevExpress?

Comment: I am now using the ASP.NET Telerik controls on a webserver to generate a chart image. This image is then loaded in an ImageView.

Comment: and you can't just import the charting libs into your monotouch project?  I'm asking because I'm naive about monotouch at this time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of commercially available chart components with MonoTouch bindings:

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2012/08/01/shinobicontrols-monotouch-bindings-%E2%80%93-the-full-story/) - have launched a beta of their bindings
- [Steema Charts](http://www.steema.com/teechart/mobile) - have MonoTouch bindings

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for such a control for charting but haven't found one. I draw my graphs manually. After all it is not so big deal just a bit of math. I draw pies and bar graphs.

Comment: You should open source it :)